# Updated info added to sidebar of tumblr

Tags: tumblr

On my test tumblr here: http://ginnypig.tumblr.com I'm trying to add a line in my sidebar which logs the time when the last post was made.

For those unfamiliar with tumblr, unique tags are used for various things, so, for instance {TimeAgo} added to the post code will result is '2 hours ago' displaying beneath the post - in other words the post was added two hours ago.

I've added the line to my sidebar, and while the line shows up, the 'time ago' does not.

The code I used is:

```
<div id="updated">last post added: {TimeAgo}</div>
```

The problem I have, is that I don't understand enough about coding to know where tumblr pull this info from, and how it's connected to posts you make.

I somehow need to pull the time stamp each time I make a post, and have it display in the sidebar instead of underneath the post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The theme operator `{TimeAgo}` needs to be inside the `{block:Posts}` operator. We also need to tell Tumblr we only want the first post:

```
{block:Posts}
  {block:Post1}
  <div id="updated">last post added: {TimeAgo}</div>
  {/block:Post1}
{/block:Posts}
```

Reference: https://www.tumblr.com/docs/en/custom_themes#posts

Comment: Thank you so much! I'd convinced myself this couldn't be done, becuase I couldn't think of any way to tell the operator that it was only the last post info I needed. Brilliant!

Comment: I've noticed that when you go to the permalink page of a post, the 'time ago' changes to that of the post you're viewing on the permalink page. Would there be any way to swap 'Last post added' for 'This post added' when the user goes to a permalink page?

Comment: Never mind, did it! Can't quite believe I did, but I did. I just wrapped the 'Last post added' in {block:IndexPage} tags, and 'This post added' in {block:Permalink} tags.

Comment: Well done. Its kind of a hack using the last post, but nice work around.